# How to add a custom UIView to UINavigationBar in only one UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Okay so I'm trying to add a subview to my navigationController's navigation bar, which works perfectly, however, when pushing a detail controller, I don't want that subview from the pushing controller to be seen in the detail view controller's navigation bar.

I appreciate any help/pointers offered. To restate: I need the subview to only be displayed in the root of the navigation controller, and to not be in any detail controllers.

Here's my current code for creating and adding the navigationController's subview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    self.ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 8.5, 320, 36);
    self.ImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo"];
    self.ImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.ImageView];
}
```

Comment: why you add uiimageview on navigation bar. you can simply try setBackgroundImage

Comment: you don't know setBackgroundImage of UINavigationBar

Comment: No, that's not what I'm after at all. I'm animating a logo in.

Comment: animating means your are implement in code or use GIF image for that

Comment: could possibly post your screen shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to

1. Add a tag to your imageView.
2. Access your imageView using tag & set it's alpha to 1 in viewWillAppear of your mainViewcobtroller where you want to show this.
3. In new viewcontroller's viewWillAppear method, access the view with same tag & then set it's alpha to 0.

That's should solve your problem
Should you need code, plz comment.

Comment: I tried something similar earlier (minus the view tag approach), and what occured was as I used the default edge pop gesture, it would appear in the wrong view controller and appear to flicker.

Comment: Please use this approach & notice the viewWillAppear method rather than viewDidAppear.

Comment: I'm using viewWillAppear method, the problem is it appears instantly while using the interactive pop gesture.

Comment: Okay, it looks like the only solution for this is to use viewWillAppear in the detail controller, and use viewDidAppear in the presenting controller to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

add this line when you push to otherViewControllers

```
 [[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:101] removeFromSuperview];
```

recreate back from other viewController;

```
- (void)viewWillApper
{

    self.ImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    self.ImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 8.5, 320, 36);
    self.ImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo"];
    self.ImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.ImageView.tag =101;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:self.ImageView];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could tag the view, self.ImageView.tag = 100; Then in the detail controller's viewWillAppear:

```
 UIView view = (UIView *) [self.navigationControler.navigationBar viewWithTag:100];
 view.hidden = true;
```

and in viewWillDisappear

```
 UIView view = (UIView *) [self.navigationControler.navigationBar viewWithTag:100];
 view.hidden = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will **only** affect the invoking view ocontroller:
In the **Root** viewcontroller of your navigationController

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
        // Create / instantiate from Nib / Use already initialized UIView
        [self.navigationItem setTitleView:<your subView here>];
}
```

When you navigate to some other viewController, the subview won't be there.